# SSRS DateDiff Expression

Tags: reporting-services

Using the following datediff expression in series chart expression

=Avg(IIF((Not IsNothing(Fields!resDate.Value)) OR (Not IsNothing(Fields!    createdDate.Value)) ,abs(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,cdate(FormatDateTime(Cdate(Fields!createdDate.Value),DateFormat.ShortDate)),cdate(FormatDateTime(Cdate(Fields!resDate.Value),DateFormat.ShortDate)))),Nothing))

which return me the average days taken in Y axis
 The dates are very huge in size although from SQL it returns the correct number of days